# Make a rectangle equal to image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an imageView. I need to restrict the size of imageView to the white background imageOnly.The image is tightly bounded between right,left and top margin. I am confused on how to do at bottom, such that the image must fit in the white background only. How do I do that ?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztvQe.png

The code I am using

```
 _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 240,175,205)];
```

Frame width and height is 205*205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create one view and add this image in it, for example use bellow code..

```
 UIView *ImageBackview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 240,225,225)];
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,205,205)];
[ImageBackview addSubview:_imageView];
[self.view addSubview:ImageBackview];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your imageView as a subview of the view with the white background.

```
UIView *whiteBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,240,205,205)];
CGSize whiteSize = whiteBackgroundView.frame.size;
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,size.width,size.height)];
[whiteBackgroundView addSubview:_imageView];
```

In the example your imageView will completely fit the size of the white background view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIView *productView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 240,225,225)];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,205,205)];
    _imageView.clipsToBounds =YES;
    [productView addSubview:_imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:ImageBackview];
```